# Azure Functions Ad authentication using swagger ui says redirect.html is not found

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using Azure functions V3
Here is my start up.cs
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;

```
        builder.AddSwashBuckle(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), opts =>
        {
            opts.SpecVersion = Microsoft.OpenApi.OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0;
            opts.Title = "My test app";
            
            opts.ConfigureSwaggerGen = x =>
            {
                //custom operation example
                x.CustomOperationIds(apiDesc => apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo)
                ? methodInfo.Name
                : new Guid().ToString());

                //custom filter example
                //x.DocumentFilter<RemoveSchemasFilter>();
                //oauth2
                x.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize", configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"])),
                            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                                { configuration["AzureAd:scope"], "scope" }
                            }
                        },
                        AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize", configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"])),
                            TokenUrl = new Uri(string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token", configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"])),
                            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                                { configuration["AzureAd:scope"], "scope" }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });
                x.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                     {
                     new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "oauth2"
                        },
                                Scheme = "oauth2",
                                Name = "oauth2",
                                In = ParameterLocation.Header
                     },
                        new List<string>()
                     }
                });
                
            };
            opts.ClientId = configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
            
            opts.OAuth2RedirectPath = "http://localhost:7071/api/swagger/ui/o2c-html";
            //configuration["AzureAd:redirectURI"];
            
        });
        
        builder.Services.AddLogging();

       
    }
```

The swagger Ui is generated. However when i click on authorize it redirects to redirect.html and says not found.
This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:7071/api/swagger/ui/o2c-html#

Comment: I think you need to give redirect url which ends with /swagger/oauth2-redirect.html in both portal and in app.Have you tried that?

Comment: Which package are you using for Swagger configuration in Azure function? if you are using [this](https://github.com/vitalybibikov/AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle) package then I believe you should be using some workaround as discussed in [this](https://github.com/vitalybibikov/AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle/issues/38#event-4923129975) thread.

Comment: @kavyasaraboju-MT yes gave the redirect url in the portal as well as in the app .Didnt help

Comment: Have you changed it to /oauth2-redirect.html at the end(and please check if you have https protocol in both the places ). If done, have you exposed scopes and added permissions to the added scope by granting admin consent.Also check the type of redirect uri.Can you please check these and provide screenshots /code details regarding the same

Comment: @user1672994 Thanks for sharing this. This solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @useruser1672994  for providing insights to this. Adding this solved the problem

```
/// <summary>
    /// This is only needed for OAuth2 client. This redirecting document is normally served
    /// as a static content. Functions don't provide this out of the box, so we serve it here.
    /// Don't forget to set OAuth2RedirectPath configuration option to reflect this route.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="req"></param>
    /// <param name="swashBuckleClient"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [SwaggerIgnore]
    [FunctionName("SwaggerOAuth2Redirect")]
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> SwaggerOAuth2Redirect(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "swagger/oauth2-redirect")]
        HttpRequestMessage req,
        [SwashBuckleClient] ISwashBuckleClient swashBuckleClient)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(swashBuckleClient.CreateSwaggerOAuth2RedirectResponse(req));
    }
```